# com.apple.main-thread EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS in cellForRowAt

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, kern-invalid-address

I have experienced this crash in cellForRowAt the line number Crashlytics pointed me to was:

```
cell.table = questionTable
```

the entire case around that line is:

```
case .mcq_single:
if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "IQ_MCQCell") as? IQ_MCQCell
{
       cell.table = questionTable;
       cell.delegate = self;
       cell.qID = answerIDs![indexPath.row];
       cell.selectionStyle = .none

       if questionNA[indexPath.row]
       {
           cell.NABox.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "checkbox_selected"), for: .normal);
           cell.questionItem.isHidden = true;
       } else {
           cell.NABox.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "checkbox_up"), for: .normal);
           cell.questionItem.isHidden = false;
       }

       let cell2 = cell.formatCell(with: item, for: cell, at: indexPath)
       textHeight[indexPath.row] = cell.questionText.numberOfVisibleLines
       return cell2;
}


Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x10281a7e8 swift_unknownRetain + 8
1  AppName                        0x100f24b48 specialized InspectionItemVC.tableView(UITableView, cellForRowAt : IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell (InspectionItemVC.swift:887)
2  FlexConnect                    0x100f1f2b8 @objc InspectionItemVC.tableView(UITableView, cellForRowAt : IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell (InspectionItemVC.swift)
3  UIKit                          0x18f537ac4 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:]
4  UIKit                          0x18f538028 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:]
5  UIKit                          0x18f5168ac -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:]
6  UIKit                          0x18f2cd33c -[UITableView layoutSubviews]
7  UIKit                          0x18f1f9f00 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
8  QuartzCore                     0x189c89998 -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
9  QuartzCore                     0x189c8db20 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
10 UIKit                          0x18f20eccc -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded]
11 UIKit                          0x18f2a46f4 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:]
12 UIKit                          0x18f2a1dc4 -[UINavigationController _layoutTopViewController]
13 UIKit                          0x18f2bac64 -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:]
14 UIKit                          0x18f2ba908 -[UINavigationTransitionView _notifyDelegateTransitionDidStopWithContext:]
15 UIKit                          0x18f2ba4e0 -[UINavigationTransitionView _cleanupTransition]
16 UIKit                          0x18f234bb4 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:]
17 UIKit                          0x18f232cb8 +[UIViewAnimationState popAnimationState]
18 UIKit                          0x18f2adc48 -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:fromView:toView:]
19 UIKit                          0x18f2a3d24 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:]
20 UIKit                          0x18f2a2e14 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:]
21 UIKit                          0x18f2a2890 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews]
22 UIKit                          0x18f2a2790 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews]
23 UIKit                          0x18f1f9f00 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
24 QuartzCore                     0x189c89998 -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
25 QuartzCore                     0x189c8db20 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
26 QuartzCore                     0x189bfa36c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*)
27 QuartzCore                     0x189c21b90 CA::Transaction::commit()
28 UIKit                          0x18f1ef5c8 _afterCACommitHandler
29 CoreFoundation                 0x185bededc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
30 CoreFoundation                 0x185beb894 __CFRunLoopDoObservers
31 CoreFoundation                 0x185bebe50 __CFRunLoopRun
32 CoreFoundation                 0x185b0be58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
33 GraphicsServices               0x1879b8f84 GSEventRunModal
34 UIKit                          0x18f26067c UIApplicationMain
35 AppName                        0x100094590 main (AppDelegate.swift:23)
36 libdyld.dylib                  0x18562856c start
```

**Update:**

```
weak var delegate: inspQDelegate? 
// weak added here
var indexPath: IndexPath?
//var table   : UITableView?; table removed indexPath used instead.
```

inspQDelegate is defined like so:

```
public protocol inspQDelegate
{
    func setNA(at index: IndexPath);
    func setAnswer(at index: IndexPath, value: String);
    func setComment(at index: IndexPath, value: String);
    func scrollToMe(at index: IndexPath)
}
```

**Update 2:**
When inspQdelegate was defined like so:

```
public protocol inspQDelegate: NSObjectProtocol
{
    func setNA(at index: IndexPath);
    func setAnswer(at index: IndexPath, value: String);
    func setComment(at index: IndexPath, value: String);
    func scrollToMe(at index: IndexPath)
}
```

I received a new crash on line cell.delegate = self below:

```
case .true_false:
     if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "IQ_FlipCell") as? IQ_FlipCell {
            cell.table = questionTable;
            cell.delegate = self;
            cell.qID = answerIDs![indexPath.row];
            cell.selectionStyle = .none

            if questionNA[indexPath.row]
            {
                cell.NABox.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "checkbox_selected"), for: .normal);
                cell.questionItem.isHidden = true;
            } else {
                cell.NABox.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "checkbox_up"), for: .normal);
                cell.questionItem.isHidden = false;
            }

            let cell2 = cell.formatCell(with: item, for: cell, at: indexPath, qtype: 0)
            textHeight[indexPath.row] = cell.questionText.numberOfVisibleLines
            return cell2;
     }
```

But when defined like:

```
public protocol inspQDelegate: class
{...}
```

I did not receive this new crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are creating a retain cycle between your tableView and it's cells. Cells are dequeued and reused often, so you shouldn't be using strong references. Your cell has a delegate which is set to the tableView anyway, so you shouldn't need to set `cell.tableView`, just use the delegate.

When declaring your delegate and tableView in the cell. (I would advise NOT to have the tableView property) make sure that you use a weak reference and this should solve your issue.

```
weak var delegate: MyTableViewDelegateProtoocol?
weak var tableView: UITableView?
```

Give it a try and let me know the outcome

Here is an [article](http://www.thomashanning.com/retain-cycles-weak-unowned-swift/) that helps explain retain cycles and memory management in Swift

UPDATE:

```
public protocol inspQDelegate: class
{
    func setNA(at index: IndexPath);
    func setAnswer(at index: IndexPath, value: String);
    func setComment(at index: IndexPath, value: String);
    func scrollToMe(at index: IndexPath)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will get rid of the tableview reference and instead pass in indexpath as the table property in the cell was just used for: delegate?.setNA(at: table!.indexPath(for: self)!); But I should also change my delegate to weak var? Should I be doing this in every cell's class that has a delegate? I will make the change but I wont know of the outcome straight away as this crash has only just came in after months of using the app i.e. I cannot reproduce it. Unless you can advise on how i might be able to reproduce?

Comment: yes, when you declare a variable like `var tableView` you are using a strong reference. in closures and for delegates its best to use a weak reference. you will notice that IBOutlets are all weak vars

Comment: Is it best practice for all properties in my tableview cell to be weak? or just delegates?

Comment: I've added a link above which would help explain. not all things should be weak. weak references could be lost and then you will get a nil value. If you aren't sure, use them for outlets, closures and delegates.

Comment: ok thanks, I'll change all delegate in all tableview cells to be weak vars and give the article a read!

Comment: When I changed my delegate to weak var I get an error: 'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types not 'inspQDelegate'

Comment: update your question with your code, show your cell and inspQDelegate

Comment: I've updated the answer, just inherit class in your protocol.

Comment: thanks i had just found that answer myself. is there any advantage of inheriting from class rather than NSObjectProtocol?

Comment: not that I am aware of, i think it's pretty much the same thing

Comment: @pearl7721 I can't be sure if it solved the crash as it wasn't happening for me anytime I run the code myself through xCode. It happened with an external user and it's the first time it did happen so I'm not sure how I can reproduce?

Comment: @Scriptable.. something of note: i have multiple question types which each have their own associated tableViewCell class, but all implement this inspQDelegate protocol. When I inherited from NSObjectProtocol I received a crash when another cell was setting its delegate. I'll add this part to the question for clarity. But when I inherited from class in my inspQDelegate protocol, this crash did not happen

Comment: thanks for note, I don't fully understand the difference between using class/NSobject in this case but I will investigate it for clarification.

Comment: @Scriptable I'll mark this as accepted for now and if the problem re-occurs I'll get back here!